# Bold text in a text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bold text in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322895/bold-text-in-textarea)

My user is typing in a textarea, using js they have the ability to make url links within this area, is there a way to bold the text in the textarea so a user can see where they have made the links?

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bold+text+in+a+textarea) shows two duplicate SO questions within the first 3 results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a [WYSIWYG editor](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/05/06/25-wysiwyg-editors-reviewed/)? For example the editor in which you typed your question in this site is [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) and it allows to bold the text.