# how to create a dynamic text area or text field in php

Tags: php, html, textarea

I need to create a text area wherein the user can adjust the font, color, or make it bold or italic. Just like here in the stackoverflow or the one you can see on forums. And when I display the output from the database, it will be displayed as it is.

Comment: Good luck.  Or use one of the dozens upon dozens that can be found in a simple Web search.

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "WYSIWYG editor". A very popular one is http://ckeditor.com

Comment: so I'll just attach that thing to my page for example and I can get the value generated by the user and save it to database together with the html tags or format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bold text in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322895/bold-text-in-textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of WYSIWYG/Markdown based text editors available. Here are a few.

- [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/)
- [Redactor](http://redactorjs.com/)
- [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/)

Another useful resource: [10 Feature-Packed Javascript WYSIWYG And Rich Text Editors](http://www.queness.com/post/10363/10-feature-packed-javascript-wysiwyg-and-rich-text-editors)

Comment: Thanks!, So I'll just attach it to my page. But it is possible to get the value typed and insert to the database together with the html formats? and output it as it is ?

Comment: Glad I could help. :) Yes ofcourse. Read the documentation to figure out how to incorporate them to your site. Its usually pretty easy to get them up and working.

Comment: Thanks. Okey I will just read the documentation. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Another very easy one, if you don't like the other ones are nicedit.com